# Name and nationality change after entry denial, does this affect anything?

Tags: visas, switzerland, denial-of-entry

I recently changed my name and I was wondering if that’s going to affect my travel to Switzerland.

I was given an entry refusal back in 2011 and my name was different back then, I changed my name due to religious reasons and I’d like to travel to Switzerland again with a different citizenship/passport, not sure if I’m going to have issues with custom & immigration agents.

I had a Australian passport back then and now I’m a US Citizen, I was only refused entry because I’m a white guy dressed like a Muslim man

Comment: Welcome to Travel.SE.  Swiss law does not forbid being a white guy dressed like a Muslim: what was the stated reason for refusal, and where exactly did this happen?

Comment: I wasn’t given any reasons, they asked me why Im in Switzerland and I said tourist , I had 1000euros on me and I showed him my gf home address where I was supposed to stay at. They took my passport for about 20 minutes , the I was told that I wasn’t allowed in the country and I was sent back the next day

Comment: " I was only refused entry cuz I’m a white guy dressed like a Muslim man" -- I wouldn't believe that even of the United States but to presume that of the Swiss border guard is absolutely ludicrous.

Comment: Im confused, how does one "dress like a Muslim man"?  The muslim men I work for all seem to dress the same way as I do... Do you mean you were wearing some traditional garb, a head dress of some description, or some specific ethnic outfit?

Comment: @Jesii Lebron Did you give biometrics at any point when you were refused entry?

Comment: @chx There are definitely parts of Switzerland which are very conservative and not particularly Muslim friendly.  A 2009 referendum forbade the building of minarets.

Comment: @chx you do realize that some EU countries such as the UK allow their immigration officers to discriminate based on race, right?

Comment: You wanted to stay *with* your girlfriend in Switzerland? Did you tell them this? This may be the *prime* reason..

Comment: No I don’t remember giving biometrics and I know some people might seem surprised by the whole thing but it still doesn’t make sense to me too. I felt like ok whatever , they’re not letting me in and it’s their country so I’m just gonna cooperate ,be quiet and came back. I was not dressed like a holy man or anything , I just had a small beard and a shirt with some Arabic letters on it and I guess that got them worried or something but my questions is , should I even try again ?

Answer (score 3):

- Whenever a form asks about name changes, you have to tell the truth.
- Whenever a form asks about citizenship changes, you have to tell the truth.
- Whenever a form asks about past refusals, you have to tell the truth.

Trying to conceal any of this *might* work if your biometrics are not on file, but sooner or later the lies will catch up with you.

Getting caught in a lie will cause a refusal of your application and for many countries also a ban for a long time.

Having been refused entry in the past will cause greater scrutiny of your application, but not an automatic refusal. The best way to make this greater scrutiny go away is if you get a Schengen visa approved *and* enter and leave without incident or overstay.

Comment: Unless the denial was for fraud or national security, I highly doubt they have retained information about it. He could try and request what data they hold about him under EU’s data protection act to confirm this.

Comment: @greatone, would it matter? Look at the Schengen C form, it doesn't go into that old stuff.

Comment: Probably wouldn’t matter for the Schengen C form—which the OP does not have to fill as a US citizen anyway—but might be a good idea to know what data governments have on him for future reference. If records about an event don’t exist, that event has not happened.

Comment: @greatone, that's gambling on all relevant data being unclassified. Much smarter (and policy on Travel SE) to advise to stick to the truth.

Comment: Well, EU data protection laws require governments and organizations to disclose personal data about an individual held with some limited exceptions such as prevention of crime and national security. Most personal information held is protected, not classified. Information held about adverse immigration events are never undisclosable even if details within (such as names and methods used) might be. It’s more like a calculated risk than gambling. It’s easy to see what data officers have access to—not a lot. Not disclosing personal information later relied upon may turn into a legal nightmare.

Comment: I’ve never done anything wrong( you don’t have to believe my statement ) it just sucks that I/O could screw you over nothing and they didn’t even stamp my passport when I got sent back. Bunch of BS

Comment: @JesiiLebron, either they were racist profiling or they understood that you wanted to live with your GF and acted accordingly. I surely hope that you communicated more politely with them than with us, or that would be the explanation you're looking for.

Comment: I was very polite and I didn’t say anything . I asked one question , why am I being sent back? I couldn’t even understand what he said to me after that. Still not sure if I should try again or not